Typo3 12: Rendering Content Element Type html in Tx_news Detail View
I am using Typo3 12.4.20 with Tx_News 11.4.2, Container 2.3.6.
To publish JobDetails to Google Jobs I use a Content Element of type html inside the News Article.
As expected the Content Element is not shown in the output, but the DetailView is incorrecly rendered. Space is added after the Categories and before the main content.

I used the workarounds in the docu of tx_news with no success. I also checked all positions of the html (normal, before content, after content) - no success. I also tried the fluid fix. After all I removed the extension "Container" - no effect.
Using typo3 9 the html content element inside a news article works.
Any suggestions, hints or help are welcome.
Thanks in advance,
Volkmar

Please show the rendered html that is causing the space.

The code is too long, it is simple json following the google guidelines for job applications.
It begins with: "<script type="application/ld+json>
{
"@context": "https://schema.org/",
"@type": "JobPosting",
"title": "Vertriebsmitarbeiter (m/w/d) für die Außendienststeuerung",
"educationRequirements" : {
"@type" : "EducationalOccupationalCredential",
"credentialCategory" : "professional certificate"
},
"description":
and ending with ""

Using this Typoscript-Snippet provided by the tx_news docu in setup
lib.tx_news.contentElementRendering = CONTENT
lib.tx_news.contentElementRendering {
table = tt_content
select {
pidInList = 1
uidInList.current = 1
where = {#tx_container_parent}<1
orderBy = sorting
languageField = sys_language_uid
}
}
removes both the space and the html content element in the source code.
Without this snippet the space  in the detail view and the html content element are added in the source code.

Sourcecode:


Rhein-Sieg-Kreis&nbsp;| 

Siegburg&nbsp;|

Vertrieb&nbsp;   



  <span class="news-list-author" itemprop="author" itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
   Referenznummer: <span itemprop="name">1234</span>
  </span>     
</p>



<!-- main text -->

html content element has to be between  and  and is missing.

"News Content Elements" have been extracted into a separate (paid) Addon since EXT:news v10:
https://docs.typo3.org/p/georgringer/news/main/en-us/Addons/NewsContentElements/Index.html

I sent an email to Georg Ringer if the addon "News Content Elements" is able to solve this issue.
